# Create constructor in C

Tags: c, oop, constructor

I know C doesn't support OOP.  I don't mean to seriously with using 4 pillar of OOP like Abstraction, Polymorphism, Encapsulation, Inheritence. But I'm trying to imitating OOP in C, more correctly, just creating a blueprint with `struct` as replacement of `class` where higher level program language usually use class keyword.

In this example case, I'm trying to create `Animal` blueprint where `dog` will be an instance of Animal.

Here is `main.c`:

```
#include "animal.h"

int main(void) {
  Animal dog; // Creating a dog instance from animal blueprint...
  dog.construct = Animal_construct; // Can I make private this line?
  dog.construct(&dog, "Doge", 8); //Constructing dog... 

  // Main Code
  dog.move(&dog, "walking"); // Moving a dog...
  printf("%s weight property is %u kilograms.\n", dog.name, dog.weigth);
  printf("%s name has %u characters.\n", dog.name, dog.get_name_length(&dog));

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Doge is moving (walking)...
Doge weight property is 8 kilograms.
Getting Doge name length...
Doge name has 4 characters.
```

The output is fine, no error.

And this is `animal.h`:

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Animal Animal;
void Animal_construct(Animal *self, char *name, unsigned int weigth);

struct Animal {
  // Constructor
  void (*construct)(Animal *, name, weigth);

  // Properties
  char name[50];
  unsigned int weigth;

  // Methods
  void (*move)(Animal *, moveType);
  unsigned int (*get_name_length)(Animal *);
};

#endif
```

And this is `animal.c`:

```
#include "animal.h"

static void Animal_move(Animal *self, char *moveType) {
  printf("%s is moving (%s)...\n", self->name, moveType);
}

static unsigned int Animal_get_name_length(Animal *self) {
  printf("Getting %s name length...\n", self->name);
  return strlen(self->name);
}

void Animal_construct(Animal *self, char *name, unsigned int weigth) {
  strcpy(self->name, name);
  self->weigth = weigth;
  self->move = Animal_move;
  self->get_name_length = Animal_get_name_length;
}
```

The problem, if you see in `main.c` there's a line:

```
dog.construct = Animal_construct; // Can I make private this line?
```

So, can I just construct dog with single line statement without assigning `Animal_construct` right after dog has been instanced?

Comment: You might get away with a class specific macro. <rhetoric>What is it that makes you want to use C for purposes it is not intended for? =-O Just use an OOP language.</rhetoric>

Comment: I don't really understand why you store a pointer to a constructor function in the object itself. Why do you need this?

Comment: @UnholySheep We had this issue multiple times the last time. They all want to use C++ syntax in C. And I'm fed up investing time to find the duplicates.

Comment: I know there are already OOP program languages like C++ that support OOP, but my framework (esp-idf) for embedded system development still using C.

Comment: You can move the `dog.construct = Animal_construct` line to another function and have the function return a the animal. Then it would become a "single line statement" in `main`. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @UnholySheep did you mean `&dog`? Yeah maybe like how python always using `self` keyword when declaring method in a class.

Comment: @thebusybee If you don't want to "waste time" on a question, then don't.  People ask questions for all sorts of reasons.  Just because you or I don't find a given question interesting, doesn't necessarily mean it's illegitimate.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well, I like this site because it used to have a lot of _relevant_ and _interesting_ contents. But such questions "water" it and will drive the good ones away. It is hard to judge from the title on the quality of the question. So I need to read it completely at least. Just my $0.02. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an `Animal` instance containing the default values and then use that to initialize your other instances.

Example:

`animal.h`

```c
typedef struct Animal Animal;
struct Animal {
   // ...
};

extern const Animal animal;
```

`animal.c`

```c
const Animal animal = {.construct = Animal_construct};
```

Then, in `main.c`

```c
int main(void) {
  Animal dog = animal; // Creating a dog instance from `animal`
  dog.construct(&dog, "Doge", 8); //Constructing dog... 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: yes, that's oke, but this doesn't work if I create instance `const Animal def` outer `main.c` file.

Comment: @CitraDewi It works fine if you `extern` declare it. I updated the answer to show that.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't mean to seriously with using 4 pillar of OOP like Abstraction, Polymorphism, Encapsulation, Inheritence

Inheritance and polymorphism is kind of the same pillar, but you can get all of these in C, though it is somewhat cumbersome. Notably, constructors and RAII etc are *not* OO features, however they are handy features to have when implementing OO.

Check this out, as it answers the question: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888) The part of that post regarding member functions explains some problems in your example too:

> Note that in this example, member functions are declared in the header rather than as function pointers in a public part of the struct. Some like to use function pointers to emulate C++-like member syntax like `obj.member()` (see for example *Schreiner - Object-oriented Programming in ANSI-C*, a book which I don't really recommend), but I think that's a rather pointless feature.
>
> In C, there are no automatic constructor/destructor calls, no RAII, no `this` pointers. Meaning you have to pass along a reference to the object anyway.
>
> So rather than writing `foo.bar(&foo, stuff)` you might as well write `bar(&foo, stuff)`.

Comment: _"So rather than writing `foo.bar(&foo, stuff)` you might as well write `bar(&foo, stuff)."`_ - Yes, and I usually prepend the "member function" with the type name to make it clear to which type it belongs: `foo_bar(&foo, stuff);`

Comment: `foo.bar(&foo, stuff)`: accessing method. While `bar(&foo, stuff)`: accessing function. in complex project maybe `bar(&foo, stuff)` the `bar` name maybe already taken by another function that make confuse for reader even though it can prevented with static keyword. Also `bar` name only is vague, is that a pure function or a method. while `foo.bar()` is explicitly tell `bar` owner is `foo`.

Comment: @CitraDewi IMO, Ted's solution is usually better.  `foo.bar(&bar)` means you need to store a function pointer in the struct.  It's not a true "method." That is *data*.  In languages like C++ (generally speaking), the methods do not take up space in the class.  The compiler is making that connection between text and data that actually doesn't really exist.  This becomes a huge waste of space if there is an array of `foo` types or there are lots of "methods." All you have done is imitated OOP *syntax*, not the *behavior*.

Comment: ... If you really want the OOP syntax without the drawbacks of storing all the function pointers, the best method is usually to store a static vtable somewhere, then reference that vtable in the struct (sort of how C++ does virtual methods).  Then you are paying the price of a single pointer no matter how many methods there are.  But now your syntax turns into `foo.vtable->get_stuff(&foo);`.  Maybe you could use some macro magic to make that look better.

Comment: @Jason from your explanation, the conclusion is more I create instance (eg: Cat), more same function pointer will be stored, because method is not pure method, but that's a data (cmiiw).

Comment: @CitraDewi, you got it. There is always a trade-off. What you really want is a namespace which is what Ted is imitating. If there was one thing c programmers wish they could steal from c++, it would be proper namespaces. All of this is just my opinion though. Depending on your use case, the extra space wasted in extra pointers may be 100% negligible in the real world anyway.

Comment: OOP or not, you should always name functions belonging to a certain module with a prefix, so that it becomes clear where they belong. With disciplined identifier naming, you don't really need namespaces.